# Exporting Video in full screen with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

i'm trying to do some animations to a video (after recording) and then export it.
but before any animation  i had the problem with the orientation which became landscape (without export it was portrait) and it is solved not but now i have problem with making it full screen.in iphone 6,7 plus its full screen how ever in ipad it is not.

here is my method :

```
func export(_ url : URL) {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)

    let track =  asset.tracks(withMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = track[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)

    let compositionVideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timerange, of: videoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    for audioTrack in asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) {
        do {
            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }

    let size = self.view.bounds.size

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = self.view.bounds.size
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)

    let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)


    let ratio = size.height / videoTrack.naturalSize.width

    composition.naturalSize = videoTrack.naturalSize

    layerinstruction.setTransform(videoTrack.preferredTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.645 , y: ratio).translatedBy(x: self.view.bounds.height, y: 0), at: kCMTimeZero)

    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]

    let filePath = self.fileName()
    let movieUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    guard let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
    assetExport.videoComposition = layercomposition
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = movieUrl
    assetExport.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport.status {
        case .completed:
            print("success")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: movieUrl)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
            break
        case .cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
            break
        case .exporting:
            print("exporting")
            break
        case .failed:
            print("failed: \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            break
        case .unknown:
            print("unknown")
            break
        case .waiting:
            print("waiting")
            break
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try any other preset other than `AVAssetExportPreset`?

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with your `layercomposition.renderSize` you are setting it for the current view so if you run this on a phone the output video will be smaller on the iPad. Can you set the renderSize to the size of the original video? That might do the trick.

Comment: maybe this one where the ratios is calculated by height/width: let ratio = size.height / videoTrack.naturalSize.width

Comment: @Bluewings yes i did the problem was with the calculation of scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what fixed my problem was changing the scale factor and the translated amount. here is the code below :

```
    let size = self.view.bounds.size
    let trackTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
    let xScale = size.height / videoTrack.naturalSize.width
    let yScale = size.width / videoTrack.naturalSize.height


    let exportTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform.translatedBy(x: trackTransform.ty * -1 , y: 0).scaledBy(x: xScale , y: yScale)
```

Comment: where did you plug in exportTransform ?